# Youtube Data API Making a comment (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, api, youtube

I'm currently trying to create a new thread using the Youtube API. Here is the example provided:

```
def comments_insert(service, properties, part, **params)
    resource = create_resource(properties) # See full sample for function
    params = params.delete_if { |p, v| v == ''}
    response = service.insert_comment(part, resource, params)
end

comments_insert(service,
    {'snippet.parent_id': 'pS16m0FttKk',
     'snippet.text_original': ''},
     'snippet')
```

I'm essentially using their exact sample code but I'm getting an error that reads: `ArgumentError - unknown keyword: snippet:`

```
resource = ChannelbackController.create_resource({'snippet.parentId': '123', 'snippet.textOriginal': message})
            response = service.insert_comment('snippet', resource).inspect
```

Comment: are you using the google client library for the Youtube API that google has created? https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/code_snippets click on the slider for the full sample

Comment: btw here's some sample code as well: https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/tree/master/ruby

Comment: Answered my own question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44769985/youtube-api-v3-insert-comment-issue?noredirect=1#comment76520916_44769985).

Comment: Close/delete this one then?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev can't delete until bounty is closed