# Youtube API V3 Insert Comment Issue

Tags: ruby, api, youtube

I'm essentially using the sample code provided by the docs [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/insert) but I'm getting an error that reads `ArgumentError - unknown keyword: snippet`. Does anyone else have this problem as well? I'm not sure if this is a valid bug but intuitively the sample code they provide should work right?

```
properties = {
                'snippet.parentId': '123',
                'snippet.textOriginal': message
            }
            resource = create_resource(properties)
            response = service.insert_comment('snippet', resource)
```

Comment: do you have 'snippet' in quotes?

Comment: @MiguelMota yeah I tried to essentially just copy and paste their sample code over with minor changes. I've updated my post to show what I currently have written. Upon further debugging, the issue seems to be that the `snippet` in `snippetparentId` and `snippettextOriginal` is not being recognized

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upon digging through the actual library, I discovered that the way to pass in the snippet part is as follows:

```
snippet = Google::Apis::YoutubeV3::CommentSnippet.new(parent_id: parent_id, text_original: message)
comment = Google::Apis::YoutubeV3::Comment.new(snippet: snippet)

response = service.insert_comment('snippet', comment)
```

Hope this saves someone from a huge headache of having to chase through their docs

Comment: Thanks a lot @Tim, its really helpful.